# Remove specific element from array in Knockout.JS

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I am creating a multiplayer game over network so I have to react on network events.

I have this simple code, but the removePlayer method doesnt work. The addPlayer() works fine.

```
<table id="userlist2" class="tablesorter" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Queue</th>
            <th>Points</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: players">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: queue"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: score"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


function PlayerViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.players = ko.observableArray();

    self.addPlayer = function (Name, QueuePos, Score) {
        self.players.push({
            name: Name,
            queue: QueuePos,
            score: Score
        });
    }


    self.removePlayer = function (Name) {
        for (var i = 0; i < self.players().length; i++) {

            if (self.players()[i].name == Name) console.log(i);
            self.players().splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
}


players = new PlayerViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(players);

players.addPlayer('Player1', '0', '0');
players.addPlayer('Player2', '0', '0');
players.removePlayer('Player2');
```

Heres the http://jsfiddle.net/xseTc/

Comment: i updated 2 lines of your code check my answer

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You have to use the [remove function](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html#remove-and-removeall) :

```
self.removePlayer = function (Name) {
    self.players.remove(function(player) {
        return player.name == Name;
    });
    
}
```

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xseTc/3/)

**html**

```
<table id="userlist2" class="tablesorter" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Queue</th>
            <th>Points</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: players">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: queue"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: score"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**javascript**

```
function PlayerViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    
    self.players = ko.observableArray();  

    self.addPlayer = function (Name, QueuePos, Score) {
        self.players.push({
            name: Name,
            queue: QueuePos,
            score: Score
        });
    }

    self.removePlayer = function (Name) {
        self.players.remove(function(player) {
            return player.name == Name;
        });
    }
}

players = new PlayerViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(players);

players.addPlayer('Player1', '0', '0');
players.addPlayer('Player2', '0', '0');
players.removePlayer('Player2');
```

Comment: isn't it player.name() == Name ?

Comment: @karussel: ...just because not even one answered to this comment: it's a "streamlined" structure, single Player properties aren't observable.

Answer (score 12):

Working remove function:

```
self.removePlayer = function (name) {
    self.players.remove(function(player) { 
        return player.name == name
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

your code is fine except 2 error you have:

```
if (self.players()[i].name == Name) console.log(i);
    self.players().splice(i, 1);
```

first here you are executing 2 lines so to execute them both you need to use `{}` so replace it with:

```
if (self.players()[i].name == Name) {
    console.log(i);
    self.players.splice(i, 1);
}
```

second to use `splice` you done need to call your observable array with `()` so you to use it as following :

```
self.players.splice(i, 1);
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ebram/xseTc/7/)**

Answer (score 0):

If you add view models to the array of players like this:

```
self.addPlayer = function (Name, QueuePos, Score) {
    self.players.push(new PlayerVM(Name, QueuePos, Score)));
}
```

Then you can remove the player object like this:

```
self.removePlayer = function (player) {
    self.players.remove(player);
}
```

Or from within the player vm:

```
parentVM.players.remove(self);
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the best source from knockout site : https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html

You can use remove method direct -- 
self.players.remove(self.players()[i]);